# Как в русской лингвистике называется clefting?

Tags: синтаксис, терминология

Понятно, что прямого отражения английских структур вида *It was he who ate my pie* в русском нет, но есть, например, расщепление сказуемого: *Съесть-то он его съел, да ему всё мало.*

Так вот,

1. Как в русской литературе называются английские *cleft sentences*?
2. Каким термином обозначается такое расщепление сказуемого и прочий *clefting*?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что в SE есть более подходящий сайт https://russian.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @behemothus С чего бы вдруг? Тема сайтов одна и та же, и мой вопрос о названии лингвистического явления, которое существует в русском языке.

Comment: С того, что там дадут более аргументированный и достоверный ответ. Здесь вы в лучшем случае получсите дискуссию на тему, что такое клефтинг - и есть ли он ф русском языке. Впрочем, дело хозяйское. Вам ответ уже дали, вряд ли кто-то отважится его превзойти.

Answer (score 1):

О клефтинге в английском языке мы говорим в рамках актуального членения - это один из способов актуализации, выделения части предложения как главной новой информации. Другие способы - синтаксическая инверсия (Я пошёл в школу, пошёл я в школу, в школу я пошёл), фразовое ударение, использование морфологических средств - усилительных частиц и наречий (только, именно, всегда и т.д.), а можно выделить с помощью особых усилительных конструкций с использованием клефтинга - расщепления.

В русском языке такого понятия **нет.** Есть только **расщепленное сказуемое.** Нам трудно представить суть расщепления. Можно только представить обратную трансформацию конструкции. Как мы распознаём фразеологизм, клише? Мы заменяем его одним словом, а вот в клефтинге мы к основному слову добавляем что-то вспомогательное и акцентируем внимание на главном. Вот, например, расщеплённое сказуемое:

Простые глагольные сказуемые иногда выражаются с помощью клише глагольного типа, например: вести борьбу (бороться), давать советы (советовать), оказывать помощь (помогать), питать ненависть (ненавидеть), принимать участие (участвовать), производить осмотр (осматривать), проявлять интерес (интересоваться).

Подобные конструкции в некоторых случаях придают высказыванию канцелярский характер, например: «производить проверку письменных работ» (вместо проверять письменные работы), «использовать применение новых методов» (вместо применять новые методы).Вот такие конструкции иногда в науке называют «расщепленным» сказуемым (глагол-сказуемое заменяется сочетанием однокоренного существительного с полузнаменательным глаголом)

Получается, клефтинг сказуемого - это замена глагола глагольным фразеологизмом-клише.

С предложением нечто другое.

Ваш пример структуры вида It was he who ate my pie - включает **эмфатический** (усилительно-экспрессивный) **оборот** - сочетание it is ... that (which, who).
С помощью таких оборотов происходит выделение подлежащего, прямого и косвенного дополнений и обстоятельств:

> Сочетание "it is ... that" употребляется для выделения одного из
>   членов предложения. **Выделяемый член предложения ставится между двумя
>   частями конструкции, которая по форме представляет собой
>   сложноподчиненное предложение.** Конструкция "it is ... that" **на
>   русский язык не переводится**, она лишь **указывает границы**
>   выделяемой части предложения.
>
> **В русском языке таким предложениям соответствует простое предложение, в котором перед выделяемым членом добавляются
>   усилительные слова "именно", "как раз", "только" (чаще при выделении
>   обстоятельства времени), "лишь"; в предложениях с отрицанием - "вовсе
>   не", "совсем не":**

https://studexpo.ru/194046/angliyskiy/emfaticheskie_sredstva_konstruktsii
https://engblog.ru/ways-to-emphasize-speech

Эмфаза с использованием предваряющего It, которая чаще всего передаётся на русский словосочетанием Именно/Никто(Ничто)иной(е)+объект. При этом It и относительное местоимение или союз не переводятся.

Похожие предложения в русском языке: Это был не кто другой, как мой друг. Мы увидели не кого  иного, как нашего директора. Это простое предложение с экспрессивным усилением (**не кого иного, как**), по форме напоминающее СПП с придаточным.Предложение как бы расколото, расщеплено, но оно одно.

В русском языке есть понятие **структурная избыточность**, вот оно похоже на клефтинг. Вот, например, именительный темы. Обращение к конструкциям с именительным темы является результатом желания источника информации донести до получателя информации **центры высказывания раздельно, последовательно,** тем самым говорящий или пишущий обеспечивает, гарантирует понимание, а следовательно, структурная избыточность конструкций с именительным темы, безусловно, коммуникативно значима: *"Москва, она, брат, всем городам мать"* Зафиксировано внимание на теме, а потом информация по этой теме. Именительный темы не является номинативным предложением, значит, это тоже простое расщеплённое предложение.

Один из приёмов экспрессивного выделения - парцелляция - расщепление предложения на отдельные части - парцеллы: У Елены беда тут стряслась. Большая. (Панфёров) Только здесь буквальное расщепление, избыточность пунктуации, а не избыточность конструкции.

Есть ещё  конструкции с простым глагольным сказуемым, которые можно перепутать  с многоглагольными:

1) сказуемое, выраженное повторением глагола, иногда с добавлением частиц **так, не,например**: *Спорили, спорили и ни до чего не доспорились* (ср.; Они долго спорили); *Вот уж наелся так наелся*; *Сам работать не работает, да и другим мешает;*

2)сказуемые типа *взял да и сделал наоборот* (ср.: неожиданно сделал наоборот), *возьму и нагряну* к вам (с глаголом взять в различных формах и другим глаголом в тех же формах);

3) сказуемые типа *пойду посмотрю* (ср.: пойду и посмотрю); *сходи узнай* (оба глагола употребляются в одинаковой форме).

Здесь расщепление в том, что одно действие передаётся двумя глаголами.

Так что, может быть, возможно сказать, что в русском языке клефтинг - это **структурная избыточность для экспрессивного выделения** (эмфазы).

Answer (score 0):

[***Грамматический способ маркирования темы***](http://genling.spbu.ru/Staff/Kasevich/publicat/semsinmo.pdf) имеет по крайней мере
три разновидности. Первая — это использование специальных словоформ,
предназначенных именно для передачи темы...

Третья разновидность — это прием так называемого **клефтинга**, т. е.
употребление оборотов наподобие англ. it is ... that (who), франц. c’est ...
que (qui) и т. п.

Comment: Галина, а зачем перед многоточиями пробелы?

Comment: Тёмыч, я же скопировала... ну, не увидела. Это надо правило искать про три точки внутри фразы. В скобках, штоль? )))

Comment: Я думал, что точно так же.